# The method setAuthorities(Set<Role>) is not applicable for the arguments (Set<String>)

Tags: spring, spring-security, roles

How do I add a role to User?

User.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AppUser {
    
    @Id
    @Column(name ="domainname", unique=true)
    private String domainName;
    
    @Column(name ="username")
    private String userName;
    
    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name ="password")
    private String  password;
    
    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name="user_role_junction",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="domainName")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="role_id")}
    )
    
    private Set<Role> authorities;
    
    public AppUser() {
        this.authorities = new HashSet<>();
    }
}
```

Role.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="roles")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="role_id")
    private Integer roleId;
    
    private String authority;
    
}
```

UserController.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private final UserService userService;
    
    @PostMapping("/register")
    public AppUser register (@RequestBody AppUser appUser) {
        if (appUser.getAuthorities() == null) {
            appUser.setAuthorities(Set.of("user"));
        }
        return userService.register(appUser);
    }
    
}
```

UserService.java

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserService {
    
    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    
    public AppUser register(AppUser appUser) {
        return userRepository.save(appUser);
    }

}
```

UserRepository.java

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<AppUser, String> {
}
```

WebConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain (HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                    .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                    .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                            .requestMatchers("login", "register").permitAll()
                            .requestMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                            .anyRequest().authenticated()
                     )
                    .logout( logout -> logout.permitAll())
                    .build();
    }
}
```

I tried to setAuthorities with a role of "user" to add a default role for a new user created. However, I'm getting an error: "The method setAuthorities(Set<Role>) in the type AppUser is not applicable for the arguments (Set<String>)".

Answer (score -1):

Set authorities not in constructor as new HashSet, just set it in field, like this:

```
private Set<Role> authorities = new HashSet<>();
```

probably will fix your issue